# Why is this an unchecked cast? And how to fix it?

Tags: java, generics, iterator

I have the following code:

```
public final <T extends Component> T getComponent(Class<T> type) {
    Iterator<Component> it = components.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Component next = it.next();

        if(type.isAssignableFrom(next.getClass()))
            return (T)next; // Why is this an unchecked cast from Component to T?
    }

    return null;
}
```

And for some reason, `return (T)next;` is an unchecked cast from Component to T.

I'm not sure as to why this is, because T has to extend Component, it should be able to safely cast it to any subclasses of Component, right?

If I manually do `return (TestComponent)next;` and change the return type to TestComponent it works fine, so why doesn't it work with T?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Others have described the problem, here is the solution with cleaner test:

```
if (type.isInstance(next)) {
    return type.cast(next);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's an unchecked cast because the compiler cannot be sure that `next` is a `T`. All it knows is that it's a `Component`.

As for your question about why casting to a `T` generates the warning, but not casting to a `TestComponent`, that's a lot more subtle. Casting to a `TestComponent` is inherently less dodgy than casting to a `T`. If `test` is not a `TestComponent`, the cast to a `TestComponent` would cause a `ClassCastException` at runtime. But this isn't the case for casting to a `T` because the type `T` is not known at runtime, due to type erasure. If you cast a `Component` that is not a `T` to a `T` and then add the result into a `List<T>`, you would have a `List<T>` where not all of the items are `T`s. This would break the guarantee that generics are supposed to provide. There would be no chance of a `ClassCastException` preventing this.

In your case, you don't need to worry. You have checked the cast to a `T` is safe by passing the `Class<T>` object and doing the check. You have two choices. You *could* suppress the warning and add a comment explaining why it's safe to do so. However, a better alternative would be to write `return type.cast(next);` instead. This doesn't generate a warning because `type.cast(object)` *would* throw  a `ClassCastException` if `object` were not a `T`.

Comment: It is never correct to use @SuppressWarnings, for the same reason it is never correct to do 'catch (Exception)'.  "I'm sure I didn't make a mistake" is not a good enough reason;  people do make mistakes, and methods get modified later down the road.

Comment: @VGR That's nonsense. If you can prove something is safe, it's perfectly ok to suppress the warning and add a comment explaining why it's ok. That's the advice of Josh Bloch in Effective Java anyway.

Comment: @pbabcdefp is correct. It is ok to suppress warnings when you are absolutely sure that the code will not cause a problem e.g. a runtime exception. Make sure the suppression of the warning covers the smallest possible scope.

Comment: @DermotBlair Actually I think I was only half correct. If you really have no other choice it's ok to suppress a warning as long as you can prove it's safe. But in this case, you do have a choice as you can write `return type.cast(next);` as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah I agree, when you have a choice it should not be used. And in this example, it should definitely not be used. It should only be used when you are required to eliminate compiler warnings (e.g. company policy) and you know for sure that the code is guaranteed to be safe. However @VGR states "It is never correct to use @SuppressWarnings" and I think that is slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As T is a subclass of Component, every T is a Component but not every Component is a T.

If a subclass inherits from a superclass, casting the superclass to the subclass cannot be performed successfully.

Therefore a new Component cannot be cast to a T instance.

Comment: I see, however in my case the line ``if(type.isAssignableFrom(next.getClass())) {`` makes sure ``next`` is of type ``T`` right?

Comment: Yes `isAssignableFrom()` checks if type is the same or is a superclass/superinterface of `next.getClass()`. Therefore if `T` is the same type as `Component`, this will return true but you still cannot cast from a `Component` to a `T` instance as not every `Component` will be a `T` instance and therefore the compiler does not allow it.

Comment: I see, so technically it did check if ``next`` was an instance of ``T``, but the compile doesn't know that, thus giving a warning.

Comment: Yes sorry, I got mixed up in my comment above. It checks if `next` is an instance/superclass/superinterface of `T`, not the other way around like I said in my comment above. i.e. it checks if the paramater passed into `isAssignableFrom()` is an instance/superclass/superinterface of the object that the call to `isAssignableFrom()` is referring to.